# htacces rewrite rule from normal url to php parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm banging my head against this one and am hoping for some help.

I'd like to get my rewrite to do the following for any VARIABLE

http://x.com/info/VARIABLE

to

http://x.com/a/info/index.php?product=VARIABLE

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could do it, in /.htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^info/(.*)$ a/info/index.php?product=$1 [L]
```

The regex part (.*)$ captures all string following info/ and passes it to the destination by $1 backreference, just as your VARIABLE part.